# fabric.js move image while keeping its depth?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image]

As shown in the picture above, image B is layered behind image A, then I set image A `selectable: false`.

My question is, is it possible to allow a user to move image B while keeping image B layered behind image A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is `preserveObjectStacking`. Set it to true when you initialize your canvas to prevent object selection from modifying the layer order.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
});
```

Comment: after add preserveObjectStacking, I can not move image B, but I can scale it and rotate it

Comment: with setting the image A `evented: false` and the option you provide, it finally works !!!